# using f-string sql query in python

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a function that returns a pandas read sql call:

```
def recommendations_for_user(user_id, threshold=4.5):
    # Join with the courses table
    query = """
    SELECT title, rating FROM recommendations
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses.course_id = recommendations.course_id
    WHERE user_id=%(user_id)s AND rating>%(threshold)s
    ORDER BY rating DESC
    """
    # Add the threshold parameter
    predictions_df = pd.read_sql(query, db_engine, params = {"user_id": user_id, 
                                                             "threshold": threshold})
    return predictions_df.title.values
```

I've tried instead to use f-strings as this is the recommended newer approach:

```
def recommendations_for_user(user_id, threshold=4.5):
    # Join with the courses table
    query = f"""
    SELECT title, rating FROM recommendations
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses.course_id = recommendations.course_id
    WHERE user_id={user_id} AND rating>{threshold}
    ORDER BY rating DESC
    """
    # Add the threshold parameter
    predictions_df = pd.read_sql(query, db_engine, params = {"user_id": user_id, 
                                                             "threshold": threshold})
    return predictions_df.title.values
```

But that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: "I've tried instead to use f-strings as this is the recommended newer approach" - f-strings may be newer, but that doesn't mean they're universally better or that you should automatically try to use them everywhere. You *definitely* shouldn't use them here - you're not even doing string formatting. This is a parameterized SQL query, not a string formatting operation.

Comment: What would happen if the user_id is `ID_XX OR 1 = 1 —?

Answer (score -1):

I use f strings all the time for SQL queries. Redshift, RDS, MySql, Sqlite no issues.

My guess is user is a string so it needs single quotes. If it is indeed a long or int then it must be some other issue.

```
query = f"""
    SELECT title, rating FROM recommendations
    INNER JOIN courses ON courses.course_id = recommendations.course_id
    WHERE user_id='{user_id}' AND rating>{threshold}
    ORDER BY rating DESC;
    """
```

Comment: If `user_id` didn't come from internet, then f-string interpolation "works", kind of. But that doesn't mean it's right, as Little Bobby Tables is happy to remind you. https://xkcd.com/327